# To have unique group name within Account, having sub-accounts

Tags: mysql

DB design for the below usecase:

Account will have multiple sub-account. Account and sub-account will also have groups within it. The group name should be unique within account, How can have DB design for this?

```
Account (table)
|------> Group (table)
          |----> GroupA (Value for Group table)
|------> Subaccount1 (table)
          |----> Group (table)
          |      |----> GroupA (Value for Group table. This should not be allowed).
                 |----> GroupB (Value for Group table.)
          |----> Subaccount2 (table)
                 |-----> Group (table)
                         |-----> GroupB (This should not be allowed, as the parent subaccount has it in its group)
```

Comment: Why `Group` is allowed in `Subaccount`'s subtree whereas `GroupA` not allowed? or `Group` is a fake, and the linking scheme must be `GroupA`<-`Account`->`Subaccount`->`GroupA` where the last (most right) `GroupA` is not allowed?

Comment: If let say you have a `groups` table, Is it possible to have two different groups with one and the same?

Comment: Why group with the name `Group` is allowed?

Comment: @Akina : In sub-account, there can be some groups by itself. Group name in account should not repeat in sub-account group name

Comment: :facepalm: `Group` and `GroupA` words in your scheme means two separate groups with different names? or there is only one group with the name `GroupA`, whereas the word `Group` is not a group name and means that `Account` and `Subaccount` are "containers" which may include some groups?

Comment: Group is a container, GroupA is group name.

Comment: @mitkosoft : Within an account, two groups cannot have same name. Across account same group name is allowed

Comment: @Pooja, you didn't get my question correctly. Is it possible to have two groups with one and the same name in general? My question is not related to the relation between accounts and groups, but with the existence of the groups itself.

Comment: @mitkosoft, having two same group names in general is not right. In the requirements, i have account concept as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will have 2 tables:

```
(a) table ACCOUNTS with these columns:
id = primary key
name = account name (with unique key on it)
parent_id = foreign key into table ACCOUNTS to represent sub-accounts

(b) table GROUPS with these columns
id = primary key
name = group name
sub_acc_id = foreign key into table ACCOUNTS (NULL if this group is attached to account only)
acc_id = foreign key into table ACCOUNTS (either the account where this group is attached to, or the parent of `sub_acc_id`)
```

There should be a unique key on columns (acc_id, name) to obey your requirement for group names.

<s>Of course this will not work if you want more than 1 level of hierarchy.</s>

UPDATE - after some thinking it looks like this data model will work with unlimited  levels of hierarchy - but you will have to maintain the proper ACC_ID in table GROUPS when you move sub-accounts between accounts.

Explanation:

A group name can be attached either to `account` (one whose PARENT_ID is NULL) or to `sub-account` (one whose PARENT_ID is not NULL). In the first case we already know the root of the hierarchy tree (account itself) but in the second case we need both the `sub-account` (where the group name is attached) **and** the root of the given hierarchy tree - if we want to use a unique key to impose the constraint from our requirements (that is - to avoid using a trigger for this).

So, when we want to attach a group name to an `account` we use the column `acc_id` and put a NULL in column `sub_acc_id`. When we want to attach a group name to a `sub-account` we use the column `sub_acc_id` and put the grand-grand... ancestor of this sub-account into `acc_id`.

Since all sub-accounts under a given account will have the same `acc_id` value - we can put an unique key on columns `(name, acc_id)` in table GROUPS and this key will prevent the same name under the same root account but will allow 2 accounts to have the same group name.

Comment: Subaccount can have n level of hierarchy.

Comment: Ivo, if we have two groups with one and the same `name`, but with different `id`, then such a unique key would be wrong, i.e. the approach would be different. That's why I have asked for such a possibility.

Comment: @mitkosoft If we try to have the same `name` and `acc_id` for 2 different rows in table GROUPS then DB will not allow this. If we try the same `name` with different `acc_id` - then DB will allow this.

Comment: You do not need `sub_acc_id`, as `ACCOUNT` has `parent_id` and a tree can be built...

Comment: @IVO, How will this work, if account containing sub-accounts, which grows n level?

Comment: @IVO, Sub-accounts having nested sub-accounts will not work.

Comment: @Pooja It will work if you use the term `account` only for those tuples which have PARENT_ID of NULL. But if you use the terms `account` and `sub-account` for any parent-child combination (e.g. calling `account` an entity on level 3 of your hierarchy and calling `sub-accounts` each of its immediate children on level 4 of the hierarchy, which in turn will be called `accounts` for any children on level 5) - then the proposed data model will not work.